# c# tooltip help

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

I am using a tooltip to display information when the user mouse_hovers on treeview nodes.  That side of it works perfectly as expected.  However I am having difficulty with the tooltip being visible when the mouse cursor leaves the treeview control.  I have tried messing around and setting the properties such as AutoPopDelay, etc but I cannot seem to get this right.  No matter what I do, when I move the cursor to the next control, the tooltip is obstructing the users view.

Any advice please?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET or something else entirely.

Comment: Hi, this is WinForms.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing you are using the treeview's `NodeMouseHover` event to render the tooltip, right? In that case you can use the 'MouseLeave' event to hide the tooltip once you leave the treeview.

```
void treeView1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   myToolTip.Hide();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my mistake!!!  I was using mousehover events, however I changed it recently to using a standard tooltip when the user clicks on a node!  The mousehover event was not responsive enough.  Do you have any advice on this?  Thanks

Comment: Well, if you want the tooltip to hide once you leave the treeview, you could still use this event. Providing that your toolTip is accesible from the event code.

Answer (score 1):

I’m probably missing something important/obvious here, but why don’t you use the tooltip property of the treeview nodes?

To activate tooltips on the treeview:

```
treeView1.ShowNodeToolTips = true;
```

To set the tooltip of a node:

```
treeView1.Nodes[0].ToolTipText = "Blah";
```